# Why main is not declared as extern

Tags: c

When we want to use a function say `void foo(void)` in `File1.c` in my `Main.c` [ where my main function is ] - why do i not need to write:

`extern int main(void);`

In `File1.c`?

> Assuming `File1.c` and `Main.c` are in a Single TU.

Comment: "Assuming File1.c and Main.c are in a Single TU" - what does that mean? A TU is a source file, after `#include`s have been processed. The only way `File1.c` and `Main.c` can be in a single TU is if one of them `#include`s the other, or they're both `#include`d from some other file.

Comment: @Steve Jessop - i think you are mixing up a bit here... we can compile 2 source files in TU without having to necessarily include it... we just need to pass them to the compiler...i just tried it to make sure.... you just need include headers if there is any requirement, we `DO NOT` include source files - other wise at compile time they will come in FILE Scope!!

Comment: C99 standard, 5.1.1.1/1: "A source ﬁle together with all the headers and source ﬁles included via the preprocessing directive #include is known as a preprocessing translation unit. After preprocessing, a preprocessing translation unit is called a translation unit". I think you mean something other than a TU (an executable, perhaps, or a static library), but TU is not the right word for it.

Comment: @Lohit: If they are in the same TU, then one of them has #included the other, which is a bit weird.

Comment: I think i got it... i was messing up the `extern` thing which is for linkage in separate TUs and not files..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never need to write `extern` with function declarations. Functions have external linkage by default. There's a strange unexplainable habit observed in some older code: to add `extern` to all external function declarations. (This is probably what led to your question about `main`.) In reality, it is completely unnecessary, serves no purpose and only clutters the code.

You can surely declare `main` with `extern`, if you so desire. But it is totally redundant.

Answer (score 5):

For a start, functions are `extern` by default.

Furthermore, `main` is "special"; the linker treats it differently.

Answer (score 2):

Because there needs to be only one `main` in the entire part of the executable which serves as a starting point of execution. There is no need for each translation unit to have linkage to `main`.

Quote from C++ standard ( I assume this would be same case for C too )-

**ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E) 3.6.1**

> 3 [...] The linkage (3.5) of main is
>   implementation-defined. [...]